# Does jQuery isotope work in xhtml

Tags: jquery

Im implementing the basic usage of isotope since its pretty copmprehensive and i only want the 'quicksand-like' nice filtering animation effect. The only thing that does work is the * (all) filter that loads all items - clicking any other filter link item shows nothing?

Im using, XHTML Strict, jQuery 1.8.3 - i also have jQuery UI 1.10.3 and using pretty photo on the image items in my portfolio, however even if i remove prettyphoto completely from the images the behaviour is still the same, nothing filters.

All the examples i've seen online (including the Isotope website) use HTML5 is this the only way it works?? I'm trying isotope because jQ Quicksand is a waste of time with prettyphoto which is well documented on other forums as inoperable the quicksand dev isnt saying much neither the prettyphoto dev - however at lease quicksand does filter it just didnt play well with prettyphoto. Any ideas how i can get isotope to, basically, filter - nothing else fancy required - 
here's what ive got:

**[js in the page head]**

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="_layout/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="_layout/js/accordion/jquery.accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layout/js/tweet/jquery.tweetable.min.js"></script>

<link href="_layout/js/isotope/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layout/js/isotope/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).load(function(){
                var $container = $('#portfolio');
                $container.isotope({
                        filter: '*',
                        animationOptions: {
                                duration: 750,
                                easing: 'linear',
                                queue: false
                        }
                });

                $('#filter li a').click(function(){
                        $('#filter li a.current').removeClass('current');
                        $(this).addClass('current');

                        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                        $container.isotope({
                                filter: selector,
                                animationOptions: {
                                        duration: 750,
                                        easing: 'linear',
                                        queue: false
                                }
                         });
                         return false;
                }); 
        });

</script>
```

**[the css]**

```
.isotope-item {
    z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  /* change duration value to whatever you like */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
```

**[the html markup  - simplified to 2 categories for brevity]**

```
<!-- isotope filter -->
<ul id="filter"> 
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".artstart">art projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".iconstart">icon projects</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="portfolio">

            <div id="0" class="picbox artstart">            
                <div class="fixed portfolio-item-preview">              
                    <img src="pfimgs/2013/timeteam.png" width="200" height="123" alt="" />                  
                    <div class="preview-options">
                        <a href="pfimgs/2013/timeteampromo.png" class="lightbox" title="view large version" rel="prettyPhoto" >view large version</a>
                        <a href="#" class="view" title="Go to project page" >Go to project page</a>                     
                    </div>      
                </div>                  
            </div>


            <div id="1" class="picbox iconstart">            
                    <div class="fixed portfolio-item-preview">                
                            <<img src="pfimgs/2013/bonecollector.png" width="200" height="123" alt="" />                   
                            <div class="preview-options">
                                    <a href="pfimgs/2013/bcollectorpromo.png" class="lightbox" title="view large version" rel="prettyPhoto" >view large version</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="view" title="Go to project page" >Go to project page</a>                        
                            </div>        
                    </div>                    
            </div>



            <div id="2" class="picbox artstart">
                <div class="fixed portfolio-item-preview">
                    <img src="_layout/portfolio/mashup55.png" width="200" height="123" alt="" />    
                    <div class="preview-options">
                        <a href="_layout/portfolio/mashuppromo.png" class="lightbox" title="View large version" rel="prettyPhoto" >View large version</a>
                        <a href="#" class="view" title="Go to project page" >Go to project page</a>                     
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>



            <div id="3" class="picbox iconstart">
                <div class="fixed portfolio-item-preview">  
                    <img src="_layout/portfolio/whatnext.png" width="200" height="123" alt="" />        
                    <div class="preview-options">
                        <a href="_layout/portfolio/whatnextpromo.png" class="lightbox" title="View large version" rel="prettyPhoto" >View large version</a>
                        <a href="#" class="view" title="Go to project page" >Go to project page</a>                     
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

Any ideas whats going on here guys??

Comment: Why on earth are you using XHTML Strict?

Comment: You've got an XML failure - the `link` tag for `style.css` is missing the closing slash, so it will fail XHTML validation. And I believe XHTML requires the `script` to have the funky comment wrapper around it in order to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it, forgot to add 'itemSelector'